# Error in table state_province for Wales

Tags: upgrade

It seems that a bug must first be reported here before is can be reported as bug.
I use version 5.35.0 Joomla, but the error is created in version 5.31.alpha1.

In the table the combination 'abbrevation' and 'country_id' must be unique. But the abbrevation for Carmarthenshire must be 'CMN' (wikipedia.org ISO_3166-2:GB) en not 'CRF', that is 'Cardiff'.
(See: civicrm_state_province.tpl, 5.31.alpha1.mysql.tpl)
I found this little copy-error when i tried to import the database with phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right - good catch. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19802

FYI in my database there isn't a restriction for uniqueness for the abbreviation field - the unique constraint is defined here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/da28128b812d4ae53c52abd8073656c61bbc4cc7/xml/schema/Core/StateProvince.xml#L70-L74 and it's `name` and `country_id`.